# Codeception remains at the same page after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2, codeception

I'm testing a form in Yii2 with Codeception and when I click on submit button and expect to be redirected to another url (by javascript) after recieving a ok via Ajax.
I use `wait(3)` method to give it some time to do the redirect, but when I check the url with `dontSeeInCurrentUrl()` method I'm always at the same page.

Why is this happening?

```
<?php
$newFamily = [
    'name' => 'testFamily'
];

$I->amOnPage('/backend/web/index.php/foobar/create');
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('create');

$I->amGoingTo('try to submit without having enter a name');
$I->click('#submitBtn');
$I->expect('not to have changed of location');
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('create');

$I->amGoingTo('check that parent family select is unchecked');
$I->dontSeeCheckboxIsChecked('#isSuperior');

$I->fillField('#familynutriment-name', $newFamily['name']);
$I->click('#submitBtn');
$I->expectTo('be in another location');
$I->wait(3);
$I->dontSeeInCurrentUrl('create');
$I->seeInDatabase('family_nutriment', $newFamily);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the default PHP Browser, since you didn't mention anything else. This browser cannot handle JavaScript, so the AJAX/event isn't happening. You will need to use Selenium, or some other browser that can handle the JS.

http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#PHP-Browser

> Common PhpBrowser drawbacks:
>
> - you can click only on links with valid urls or form submit buttons
> - you can’t fill fields that are not inside a form
> - **you can’t work with JavaScript interactions: modal windows, datepickers, etc.**